# D3.js: Loading multiple networks from JSON files w/ Force Layout

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, social-networking, force-layout

I have several networks (nodes + links) that are stored in separate JSON files. I'm loading them into a Force Layout in D3.js, and individually they load and layout fine. However, I want to add the ability to load any of the files on the same page (one at a time), and have the Force Layout start over whenever a new network is loaded from the JSON file.

How do you restart the Force Layout when a new network is loaded from a JSON file? The closest I've found is http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130, but that only works with a single file.

**Strange related error?**

I've noticed something peculiar about the Force Layout also. If I rapidly change between the JSON files every 1 second, the Force Layout keeps laying them out properly. If I wait more than a couple seconds before switching over, then the Force Layout seems to settle on a final layout by the second network, then it stops laying out the rest of the networks from then on.

More details about the above: I realized that I'm getting an unexpected error when the Force Layout fails:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined
```

The error appears to be internal to D3.js, at the following lines:

```
d3_selectionPrototype.each = function(callback) {
    return d3_selection_each(this, function(node, i, j) {
        callback.call(node, node.__data__, i, j);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-start

> # force.**start**()
>
> Starts the simulation; this method must be called when the layout is first created, after assigning the nodes and links. In addition, it should be called again whenever the nodes or links change. [...]

Comment: I execute `force.nodes(graph.nodes).links(graph.links).start();` (where `graph` is the network data) every time after I load the data from a JSON file. It still seems to get locked up on something.

Comment: Oh ok. Does it work right if you initialize a new `d3.layout.force()` each time you load new data?

Comment: No dice there either. Although I just realized that it's throwing an error each time the force layout fails: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined`. I'll put the details up above in the original post.

Comment: Dev tools should give you a stack trace for this error, with line numbers. Is it being thrown by a line of your code, or by D3.js internally?

Comment: Aha! That's the `.each` function call. I went and commented out the code where I run a `.each`, and that fixed it. So now I have a rabbit hole in my code to dig through. Thank you! I'll check your answer as the answer since you technically answered the original question. :-)

Comment: FYI you can expand the error to get a stack trace, which should point to the line of your code that triggered the error. Also, assuming chrome dev tools, you can toggle the stop sign button to purple so that it pauses the runtime on error and lets you poke around.